# Why node_modules folder needs to get removed in git repo?

Tags: node.js, git, react-native, node-modules

why it is necessary to ignore node_modules from git repo?

The other users who will use my code from repo ,don't they will need my node_modules folder ?

Comment: node_modules contains "code from other repositories" that can easily be obtained from those repositories and your packages.json file will already make it so they get the exact versions they need from their original repositories.  There is no advantage and lots of disadvantage to you making a whole new repository for each of the node modules that you are using in your project.  Further the actual repositories for all those modules contain their history, their issues database, their documentation, etc...

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11459475/should-i-check-in-node-modules-to-git-when-creating-a-node-js-app-on-heroku https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17069782/gitignore-and-node-modules https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328613/why-is-the-node-modules-folder-not-committed-to-git

Answer (score 0):

These modules are external dependencies of your application and you should have added them in your `packages.json` accordingly.

You don't have to include the entire source of these packages because you can install them with a single command: `npm install`, and for many other reasons (see jfriend00 comment).

So usually, when developping an app, we add `node_modules` to `.gitignore` to prevent dependencies from being versionned.

It is not necessary (you can always do what you want), but it is strongly recommanded to leave your repo clean and maintainable.

Comment: And because it's a pain is the a** to merge it in case of conflicts

Answer (score 0):

**node_module** is too big and you already have **package.json** that helps to to install all packages in **node_module** by `npm install` / `yarn install` command.

keep small, clean and maintainable  so add **node_module** in **.gitignore** file .

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to version the whole node_modules, because you achieve the same goal using the package.json file, which is the description of the dependencies required by your application.

When other users check-in your versionned code, a simple `npm install` is enough to gather those dependencies using the description provided in the package.json file.

Cf. [Why is the node_modules folder not committed to Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19328613/why-is-the-node-modules-folder-not-committed-to-git?noredirect=1&lq=1)